# unable to play audio recordings on android using phonegap 2.4

Tags: android, cordova, audio-recording

im trying to record an audio file using Media object in phonegap and then play it. i have no problem recording, but then when i try to play it my app shuts down, both on my emulator and my device. on the logcat it says: "null pointer exception at org.apache.cordova.readyPlayer (AudioPlayer.java)". many thanks to anyone who is willing to help me, it took me a while to realize im completely lost here.
here is the code which i copied from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.stopRecord and added .play() after the .stopRecord(). i can add the manifest and activity if needed, i doubt that the problem is there but i could be wrong.
**index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Record audio
// 
function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myrecording.amr";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
        if (recTime >= 10) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = "finished";
            **mediaRec.play();**
        }
    }, 1000);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    recordAudio();
}

// onSuccess Callback
//
function onSuccess() {
    console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
}

// onError Callback 
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// Set audio position
// 
function setAudioPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
}

</script>
```

```
<p id="media">Recording audio...</p>
<p id="audio_position"></p>
```

yuval

Comment: What if you delete the mediaRec object after stopping the recording, create a new Media object with the same url and try to play that?

Comment: actualy, five minutes ago i figured it out and then i saw your ansewr. it is correct. thank you very much anyway, next time i wont struggle with it for so long before asking, you could have saved me a LOT of time :)

Comment: @user2033402 I'm currently stuggling with this issue, could you please post your solution.  I'm using phonegap 3.0 but the syntax is the same.  Why on earth would we need to delete the mediaRec object and create a new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the same issue with Cordova 3.5 (with Media plugin 0.2.11) and Android 4.4. The solution is as described above. Basically something like this should do the trick:

```
mediaRec.stopRecord();
src = mediaRec.src;  // if you don't have src defined anymore
mediaRec.release();

mediaPlay = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
mediaPlay.play();
```

Comment: Hey, do you have any idea on how to do the same thing but playing the media in another function after recording. I tried to pass the src to the function as an argument but the recorded audio is not playing, even though I use the full local path. I tried the solution from the other answer on this question too, but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create an other Media object to play the previously recorded file. Just do the following - you have to release the media object after recording is stopped:

```js
// variable in global scope
var mediaRec = 0;

// function to record an audio
function recordAudio() {
  // create media object for your recording
  mediaRec = new Media("phonegap_rec.amr", onMediaRecordSuccess, onMediaRecordError);
  // start recording
  mediaRec.startRecord();
  // recording for 5 seconds
  var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        if (recTime >= 5) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            // stop recording after 5 seconds
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
            // release the media object (THIS IS THE KEY SOLUTION HERE)
            mediaRec.release();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

// function to playback recorded audio
function playRecord() {
  // check if the object exists
  if (mediaRec) {
    // now you can playback the recording
    mediaRec.play();
  }
}
```